# what should be the position of adverb of manner in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar

Both the teams played the game fairly.
Both the teams fairly played the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that 'Both teams played the game fairly' is correct. This means that both teams participated in a sporting manner and without cheating.

Using 'fairly' before the verb sounds wrong. Normally, you would use 'fairly' in this position to modify an adjective, i.e. 'It was a fairly good game'.